# Loading geodatabase file with C# code

Tags: raster, arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, c#, esri-geodatabase

I'm trying to get a pixel value from my geodatabase. The problem is at loading the geodatabase file (.gdb). Using this code

```
Geodatabase gdb = new Geodatabase(@"C:\Data\Scotland.gdb");
Raster mtnRaster = gdb.OpenRaster("NORTHGORMS_HO");
```

C# cannot recognize `Geodatabase` as type of variable. Even when trying

```
Raster mtnRaster2 = Raster.OpenFileGeodatabaseRaster(@"C:\Data\Scotland.gdb", 
"NORTHGORMS_HO");
```

C# cannot recognize `OpenFileGeodatabaseRaster`.

It seems that I have to add the assembly `ESRI.ArcGISExplorer`, but I don't found it in my list of assemblies.

How can I fix this issue ?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 and C# under .NET 2013

Comment: You need to open the workspace with an IWorkspaceFactory cast from FileGDBWorkspaceFactory. I don't have any examples of working with GDB rasters as I find them annoying but I do have plenty of code opening feature classes and maybe mosaic dataset from GDB, would this help?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson the additional questions, which made it too broad, are gone so it is re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in how you create your `IWorkspace`, you need to do it this way:

```
IWorkspaceFactory pWSf = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactoryClass();
IWorkspace pWS = pWSf.OpenFromFile("c:\\path\\to\\file.gdb",0);
IRasterWorkspace rasterWorkspace = (IRasterWorkspace)pWS;
IRasterDataset rasterDataset = rasterWorkspace.OpenRasterDataset("name of image");
```

From an [IWorkspaceFactory](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000s00000m9w000000) cast from the correct class ArcObjects you can open the [workspace](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000s00000m48000000) and cast to [IRasterWorkspace](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000n0000037q000000) to open the raster as an [IRasterDataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000s000006qq000000).

To get a pixel value from a RasterDataset you can use an [IPixelBlock](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000s0000063r000000) from the [IRaster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/index.html#//000s000006p1000000) created from the RasterDataset to read a single cell as an array:

```
// reading occurs on the band so we need to get the band from the
// IRasterDataset using the CreateDefaultRaster method.
IRaster pRas = rasterDataset.CreateDefaultRaster();
IRasterBand pBand = (pRas as IRasterBandCollection).Item(0);
IRawPixels pRawPix = (IRawPixels)pBand;

IPnt pBlockSize = new PntClass(); // set the IPnt objects to get the cell
pBlockSize.SetCoords(1, 1);       // one for how many cells (rows cols)
IPnt pTLC = new PntClass();       // the other for what row, col to start
pTLC.SetCoords(pCol, pRow);       // reading the raster at

// create an empty pixel block then read into it
IPixelBlock pPixBlock = pRawPix.CreatePixelBlock(pBlockSize);
pRawPix.Read(pTLC, pPixBlock);
object pRetObj = pPixBlock.GetVal(0, 0, 0);

if (pPixBlock.get_PixelType(0) == rstPixelType.PT_FLOAT)
{
    float pFloat = (float)pRetObj; // get the cell value as a float (32bit)
}
```

But you must use row, column addressing for the raster not world coordinates. Row and column starts from the upper left corner of your raster and is counted in cells.